# How to set record rule for account move to show and access each user own records and their invoices in Odoo 15?

Tags: user-roles, odoo-15, odoo-accounting, record-rules

Is this possible to do this by record rule?

Example:

user A should see his own invoices and create as well invoice,
and another user B is an administrator to see all invoices
C user should only pay the bill on created invoices by A user.

so if we login to A, and go to account.move, we can see records of A user Only not other users.

if we login to B, we must see all records.

Thanks you.

I want that user only able to create/edit their own invoices and can't see other users invoices. Please help me out!!!

Thanks